# Cannot Connect to Linux Oracle Databse with Perl Script after connecting with PuTTY

Tags: linux, bash, putty

I have the following problem:

I currently connect to one of our Linux servers using PuTTY on my Windows 10 machine. If I use a ‘standard’ PuTTY connection I have no problem: I can log in and run my Perl script to access an Oracle database on the Linux server. However, recently I have set up a new PuTTY connection (I copied the original working copy used above). The only difference from the original is that I have entered the following in the section `Connection->SSH->Remote command` of the PuTTY configuration window:

```
cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl ; /bin/bash
```

(I have done this so I arrive directly in the folder containing all my scripts.)

I can still log into the server with no problems and it takes me straight to the folder that contains my Perl scripts. However, when I run the script to access the Oracle database I get the following error:

```
DBI connect('server1/dbname','username',...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc. at PerlDBFile1.pl line 10.
impossible de se connecter à server1 / dbname at PerlDBFile1.pl line 10, <DATA> line 1.
```

In addition, if I run the `env` command on the server the variable `$ORACLE_HOME` is not listed (If I run the same `env` command on the server with the standard PuTTY connection the `$ORACLE_HOME` variable is present.)

Just to note: Running any other Perl script on the server (that does NOT access the Oracle database) through either of the PuTTY sessions I have created works with no problems.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: sounds like the .profile is not being executed to set up your env in the new remote command session in putty.

Comment: so just tried this and remote command wont execute your .profile and set up your env for you so you would need to do it for yourself as part of your remote command. so in my linux server with ksh as my shell i would need to do `cd /opt/some/dir; /bin/ksh; . ~/.profile`

Comment: the problem seems like, that you run /bin/bash, on your login, which is overwriting your env from original shell session that you got on login.

can you please try to change:
cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl ; /bin/bash

to 
cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl 
and try again ? i think you will see your $ORACLE_HOME set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have the solution!...Thanks to everyone who replied.

Basically, I originally had the command:

cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl ; /bin/bash (See original post)

To get it to work I replaced the above with

cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl; source ~/.bash_profile; /bin/bash

I also tried:

cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl; /bin/bash; source ~/.bash_profile

But that did NOT work.

Hope this helps someone.

Gauss76

Answer (score 0):

When you set the remote command in PuTTY, it skips running of `.bash_profile` that is present in your default `$HOME` directory. This is why you are getting the error.

To resolve it, either place a copy of `.bash_profile` in your perl directory, or add a command to execute `.bash_profile` in remote command

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses. Unfortunately none of them work! Here is what I have tried: Regarding Chris Doyle's suggestion replacing my PuTTY command with cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl; /bin/bash; . ~/.profile does NOT help. NauT's idea on removing /bin/bash fromthe end of the command results in no session appearing!

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses. Unfortunately none of them work! Regarding Chris's suggestion replacing my PuTTY command with cd ../home/code/project1/scripts/perl; /bin/bash; . ~/.profile does NOT help. NauT's idea on removing /bin/bash from the end of the command results in no session appearing at all! Finally Lohit's suggestion produces no difference. However I did find the command . ~/.bash_profile Adding it to the end of my PuTTY command does not work but once in the terminal if I type the same thing then my program works fine! So, why is the command not functioning in my PuTTY string?

Comment: Change the order. you need to call to laod the .profile before you spawn a new shell. essentially what is happening here is the xd command gets exectuted. then the bash command is executed and opens an interactive window. only when you exit the bash window does the last command of loading the profile get executed. If you executre the profile first before the cd then cd and load the bash shell it will inherit the env thats just been set by your .bash_profile